# Scala: Use implicits in with Function interface

Tags: scala, function, implicit

In scala you can write a a function like:

```scala
object Add extends ((Int, Int) => Int) {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
```

I want to write a function like above, but i also want to use imlicit. something like:

```scala
object DoSomething extends (Configuration, ??? => Dataframe) {
  override def apply(config: Configuration)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    ...
  }
}
```

*Does anyone know, how I can do this?*

**Edit:**

```scala
object DoSomething extends (Configuration => SparkSession) {
  override def apply(config: Configuration)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val bootstrapServers = configuration.bootstrapServers
    val topic = configuration.topic

    sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()
  }
}
```

Comment: Again it would be easier if you just have a plain object, and you define your apply there, which can receive an implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class DoSomething(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession) extends (Configuration => DataFrame) {
  override def apply(config: Configuration): DataFrame = {
    val bootstrapServers = configuration.bootstrapServers
    val topic = configuration.topic

    sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that `???` I added because I didn't know how to mark the place where I thought the imlpicit definition should be or how it should look like.

Comment: @SleepyX667 Your `apply` returns `DataFrame` but there is no `DataFrame` in `(Configuration, ??? => SparkSession)`.

Comment: I added a edit comment to the question and correct the typo I made (you are right... the function should return a Dataframe

Comment: @SleepyX667 Maybe this should be `object DoSomething extends (Configuration => DataFrame)`. If method is `def apply(x: X): Y` then class `extends (X => Y)`.

Comment: @SleepyX667 You can't put `implicit` to function type. This feature will appear only in Scala 3 http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/implicit-function-types.html